# define brands for wordpress custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I have created "Track" custom post type.I want to define "top brands" and "other brands" for "Track" Post type.I don't want to create custom field for post type.any other way to define it.

Comment: you can create category for `top brands` and `other brands`

Comment: ok thanks...but i have scenario where i have custom field values "Track" and "overt the tier track".both have different brand images...means "Track" have different 'top brands' and 'other brands' and "overt the tier track" have different 'top brands' and 'other brands'...

Comment: then you can create 2 custom post type?

Comment: Track is custom field for custom post type "track".Track has the values like "Tacks" and "Over the tier track".http://bear.noesis.chat/construction-rubber-tracks/ here is the filter form what i am developing

Comment: If is select the Tracks "top 15 brands images will be displayed" and other brands will be display as a dropdown in 'Select Brand
'

Comment: Im not sure what you are asking. and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Track(custom Post type),tracks(custom field of custom post type),Tracks and over the tire track is the values for tracks custom fields

Comment: Please refer the link ''bear.noesis.chat/construction-rubber-tracks".what i  want to achieve is when i am select the Tracks.it will listed the top 15 brands images and other brand images will be displayed as dropdown

Comment: If i am select the "over the tire track" from radio buttons it will listed the top 15 brands of "over the tire track" and other brands will be listed in dropdown.now do u understand what i want to achieve ?